# Is there a list of Inform7 commands?

Tags: command, inform7

Looking for a thorough listing of Inform7 commands hasn't turned up much.

While the [manual](http://inform7.com/learn/man/ex162.html) has an index of examples, the commands are not listed.
The closest I've found is an [Inform7 cheat sheet](http://user.cs.tu-berlin.de/~moreiser/inform/Inform7_CheatSheet.pdf), which though useful, is not complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of available commands is in the IDE's Actions tab of the Index page. It has everything except swear words and some low-level commands like UNDO and OOPS. See http://www.intfiction.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=10412&start=10#p62633 for a copy-pasted list of the commands provided by the Standard Library.